# Using Spring integration AWS, how to download a file from S3 using ETag rather key i.e. fileName

Tags: spring, spring-integration-aws

Using spring-integration-aws, is it possible to download a existing file from AWS S3 using file ETag rather key. The objective to add a ETag as constrain beside the file name as headers key.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the ETag in the "If-Match" and "If-None-Match" header condition but you cannot use the ETag to replace the key name in the HTTP GET command.

[S3 Get Object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html)

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm using Spring-integration-aws. my messageHandler looks like below. Could you please advice, how can I set the headers 

``

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm using spring-integration-aws my messageHandler looks like below. Could you please advice, how can I set the header 
`  
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "s3sender")
  public MessageHandler s3handler() {
    S3MessageHandler s3MessageHandler = new S3MessageHandler(..
        true);  ..  Expression exp =
        PARSER.parseExpression("payload instanceof T(java.io.File) ? payload.name : headers.key");
    handler.setKeyExpression(exp);
   ..
    s3MessageHandler.setUploadMetadataProvider((metadata, message) -
     ...
    return s3MessageHandler;
  }`

Comment: Sam, open a new question as the topic is now different.

Comment: Thanks John, Meantime I addressed the problem, by extending S3MessageHandler to a customer handler. As the S3MessageHandle does not provide any access to GetObjectRequest.